# manually create a user with SecuredSocial

Tags: securesocial

I use securedsocial to manage the singup and login of my project. The password created by securedsocial stored in the mongodb is as below:

```
"password" : {
    "hasher" : "bcrypt",
    "password" : "$2a$10$ttFOX3YrXwQyiUVVRWL1Ku54CediP/Z/pGQ8QOP2YBKL/s87wyGba",
    "salt" : null
}
```

I now want to create a new user manually so i need to know how to encrypt the password the same way as securedsocial. Or if there is any tool to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the PasswordHasher the module uses to hash the passwords and then save them. By default SecureSocial uses BCrypt.